# Can you publish an app made with Android Studio to iOS platforms?

Tags: android

Can you publish an app made with android studio to iOS platforms? Is there a compiler that lets you compile your Android Studio app to and iOS platform working app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no something that can do that. Android is very different from IOS. If you want, there are a lot of tools that you can develop with them apps for both Android and IOS, with one codebase.

Some of these tools:

1. React Native
2. Flutter
3. Xamarin
4. PhoneGap
5. Apache Cordova

But if you will use one of these tools, instead of `Android Studio` for Android and `XCode` - It will not have the same performance as if it was written with `Android Studio` and `XCode`.

The reason for that is because the platform-specific tool (`Android Studio` / `XCode`) can talk directly with the Operating System, while the cross-platform tool (`React Native` / `Fultter` etc.),  cannot talk directly with the Operating System.

Hope I helped you!

Answer (score 1):

It is not practical to run Android apps on iOS or the other way round.

Each operating system of each platform has different native components. The native Android or iOS app development requires using different programming languages, design interface, navigation, integration process.

The Android system uses the instruction set of the Java virtual machine called ByteCode. iOS, on the other hand, implements the compiled code.

Running Android apps on iOS is not possible because of the following factors:

- Different lifecycle of apps in the system.
- Different lifecycle of app screens within the app itself.
- Different approaches regarding data access.

It is misleading to be told to use some kind of service or program to transfer your app to another platform with just a few clicks. Online tools like an Android to iOS converter do not work.

The only exception is the case if your app has been developed cross-platform from the beginning. There are some web-based libraries and frameworks which can help you develop hybrid apps. You can also have a look at flutter & xamarin but the app must be all done in that framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Flutter.

https://flutter.dev/

They are different from writing standard android apps, and use Dart rather than Kotlin/Java.

It does have a good tight integration with Android Studio however.